# How to get back to default LTS kernel releases after manual kernel upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, downgrade

I ran into a hardware issue that forced me to downgrade to a lower (5.4) kernel. But after some months the issue seems fixed and the latest kernels (5.10 at this moment). My problem now is that apparently by manually keeping the old default Ubuntu kernel, then manually upgrading by one point release, my system is no longer is downloading/installing standard release kernel updates.

I manually installed (via Mainline) the latest 5.10 kernel, but as with most kernels from Mainline, they are indicated by a Tux icon. My last default install kernel is still there, indicated with a round orange Ubuntu logo. It seems like I'm off track now.

I'd rather not keep using Mainline to download/install stable kernel updates semi-manually. How can I get "back on track" to receive the normal Ubuntu-pushed kernel updates in a standard software update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Ubuntu 20.04:

Install the `linux-image-generic` metapackage to restore the current version of the original Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.04.1 kernel (5.4)

--or--

Install instead the `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` metapackage for newer kernels, currently 5.8, same as Ubuntu 20.04.2 and 20.10.